# Capacitor near analog line sensor

Tags: capacitor, sensor, analog

Is it necessary to place a capacitor near `VCC` even if there isn't one in the datasheet? The one I am talking about is `QRE1113`. On the one hand if it isn't advised in the datasheet that it will feel like a redundant action, on the other hand it won't hurt you if you do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not necessary, because the part does not have a VCC pin. You must use this part as a component in a larger circuit, and the configuration of that circuit decides if a capacitor is needed or not.

The datasheet does not include any example designs or measurement setups, which is why having a capacitor there would not make sense.